# How to only allow openvpn client to download software from server instead of internet.

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-14.04

I have a server and several clients (all running ubuntu) with openvpn installed and configured on them.  I want to disallow my clients from installing/downloading any software independently and instead, from the openvpn server, have the administrator deploy software to the server, if need be.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, one point: this has nothing to do with OpenVPN specifically. Solving your problem as stated is really no different than solving the same problem anywhere else.

Things you'll need to do:

1. Do not give your users administrative access to their machines.
2. Configure your clients to use a proxy server that *you* run, and that has a restrictive access list of sites they can visit.
3. Use some sort of configuration management (Ansible, Chef, Saltstack, etc.) to maintain your client machines.
4. Consider mounting your `/home` partitions with the `noexec`, and ensure that `/tmp` is mounted with `noexec` as well.

The above measures will get you a long way towards accomplishing your goals.